# VStack Not Resizing Properly to ForEach Contents

Tags: user-interface, swiftui, vstack, swiftui-vstack

Consider the following setup (it's not the neatest display, but it was the quickest way I could think of to replicate my problem):

```swift
class IdentifiableString: Identifiable, Hashable {
    static func ==(lhs: IdentifiableString, rhs: IdentifiableString) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.id)
    }
    
    let id = UUID()
    var string = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var textField1Text = ""
    @State var textField2Text = ""
    @State var textField3Text = ""
    @State var textField4Text = ""
    @State var textField5Text = ""
    @State var textField6Text = ""
    @State var textField7Text = ""
    @State var textField8Text = ""
    @State var textField9Text = ""
    @State var textField10Text = ""
    @State var textField11Text = ""
    @State var textField12Text = ""
    @State var textField13Text = ""
    @State var textField14Text = ""
    @State var textField15Text = ""
    
    @State var identifibleStrings =  [IdentifiableString(), IdentifiableString(), IdentifiableString(), IdentifiableString(), IdentifiableString(), IdentifiableString(), IdentifiableString(), IdentifiableString(), IdentifiableString(), IdentifiableString(), IdentifiableString(), IdentifiableString(), IdentifiableString(), IdentifiableString(), IdentifiableString()]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button("Reset", role: .destructive) {
                textField1Text = ""
                textField2Text = ""
                textField3Text = ""
                textField4Text = ""
                textField5Text = ""
                textField6Text = ""
                textField7Text = ""
                textField8Text = ""
                textField9Text = ""
                textField10Text = ""
                textField11Text = ""
                textField12Text = ""
                textField13Text = ""
                textField14Text = ""
                textField15Text = ""
                
                for identifibleString in identifibleStrings {
                    identifibleString.string = ""
                }
            }
            
            Section {
                TextField("TextField 1", text: $textField1Text)
                    .onChange(of: textField1Text) { _, newValue in
                        identifibleStrings[0].string = newValue
                    }
                TextField("TextField 2", text: $textField2Text)
                    .onChange(of: textField2Text) { _, newValue in
                        identifibleStrings[1].string = newValue
                    }
                TextField("TextField 3", text: $textField3Text)
                    .onChange(of: textField3Text) { _, newValue in
                        identifibleStrings[2].string = newValue
                    }
                TextField("TextField 4", text: $textField4Text)
                    .onChange(of: textField4Text) { _, newValue in
                        identifibleStrings[3].string = newValue
                    }
                TextField("TextField 5", text: $textField5Text)
                    .onChange(of: textField5Text) { _, newValue in
                        identifibleStrings[4].string = newValue
                    }
                TextField("TextField 6", text: $textField6Text)
                    .onChange(of: textField6Text) { _, newValue in
                        identifibleStrings[5].string = newValue
                    }
                TextField("TextField 7", text: $textField7Text)
                    .onChange(of: textField7Text) { _, newValue in
                        identifibleStrings[6].string = newValue
                    }
                TextField("TextField 8", text: $textField8Text)
                    .onChange(of: textField8Text) { _, newValue in
                        identifibleStrings[7].string = newValue
                    }
                TextField("TextField 9", text: $textField9Text)
                    .onChange(of: textField9Text) { _, newValue in
                        identifibleStrings[8].string = newValue
                    }
                TextField("TextField 10", text: $textField10Text)
                    .onChange(of: textField10Text) { _, newValue in
                        identifibleStrings[9].string = newValue
                    }
                TextField("TextField 11", text: $textField11Text)
                    .onChange(of: textField11Text) { _, newValue in
                        identifibleStrings[10].string = newValue
                    }
                TextField("TextField 12", text: $textField12Text)
                    .onChange(of: textField12Text) { _, newValue in
                        identifibleStrings[11].string = newValue
                    }
                TextField("TextField 13", text: $textField13Text)
                    .onChange(of: textField13Text) { _, newValue in
                        identifibleStrings[12].string = newValue
                    }
                TextField("TextField 14", text: $textField14Text)
                    .onChange(of: textField14Text) { _, newValue in
                        identifibleStrings[13].string = newValue
                    }
                TextField("TextField 15", text: $textField15Text)
                    .onChange(of: textField15Text) { _, newValue in
                        identifibleStrings[14].string = newValue
                    }
            }
            
            Section {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(identifibleStrings) { identifiableString in
                        if identifiableString.string != "" {
                            Text(identifiableString.string)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've discovered that when I provide all of my text fields with some kind of input, tap on the reset button, and then scroll down to my `VStack`, I see this:

[image: Oversized VStack]

and only when I scroll my VStack off screen and back again do I find that it has properly resized itself:

[image: Properly Sized VStack]

Note: This behavior doesn't occur if the VStack's row is visible on the UI when the reset button is tapped (*e.g.* comment out text fields 10-15, or run the code on a device with a substantially larger screen (such as an iPad)).

I've also occasionally had the VStack not grow sufficiently to display all of its contents properly, but I haven't been able to consistently replicate that behavior. I attempt to do this by creating a "Set with Dummy Data" button that automatically populated all my text fields with data, but the VStack grew to the expected size.

I tried wrapping my `VStack` in an `if` block that would only allow the `VStack` to show if an `@State` bool variable in my view struct was set to `false`:

```swift
 @State var resetUpdate = false
```

```swift
 Button("Set with Dummy Data") {
    resetUpdate = true
    ...
 }
 .onChange(of: resetUpdate) { _, newValue in
     if newValue == true {
         resetUpdate = false
     }
 }
```

```swift
if !resetUpdate {
    VStack {
        ...
```

But that had no effect. Using `.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)` on the `Text` view in the `ForEach` loop doesn't do anything either. Does anyone have any guesses as to why this behavior is occurring (as well as how to prevent it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note `@State var ...` works with value type, eg `struct`, not reference type, eg `class`, unless you use the Observation framework.

Try this approach using `@Observable class IdentifiableString` and some `ForEach` loops to simplify the code.

It seems that the View does not rerender the `VStack` properly (probably another SwiftUI bug).
To force it to do so, I used an `.id()` and change its value
when the reset button is tapped.

Example code that works for me:

```
@Observable class IdentifiableString: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var string = "xxxx" // <--- for testing
    init() {  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items = [IdentifiableString]()
    @State private var id = false  // <--- here

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button("Reset", role: .destructive) {
                items.forEach{ $0.string = ""}
                id.toggle()  // <--- here
            }
            Section {
                ForEach($items) { $item in
                    TextField("TextField", text: $item.string)
                }
            }
            Section {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        if !item.string.isEmpty {
                            Text(item.string)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .id(id) // <--- here, or on Section, or List
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            for _ in 0...24 { items.append(IdentifiableString())}
        }
    }
}
```

Edit-1:

If you really need to have a `ObservableObject` then use this code,
do not **nest** `ObservableObject` and do not use your `static func == ..`
based on `id`, and no need for `func hash...`.
Also use `@StateObject` not `@ObservedObject`, such as:

```
struct IdentifiableString: Identifiable {  // <--- here
    let id = UUID()
    var string = "xxxx" // <--- for testing
}

class ItemsModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [IdentifiableString]()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var dataModel = ItemsModel()  // <--- here
    @State private var id = false  // <--- here

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button("Reset", role: .destructive) {
                dataModel.items.indices.forEach{ dataModel.items[$0].string = ""}
                id.toggle()  // <--- here
            }
            Section {
                ForEach($dataModel.items) { $item in
                    TextField("TextField", text: $item.string)
                }
            }
            Section {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(dataModel.items) { item in
                        if !item.string.isEmpty {
                            Text(item.string)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .id(id) // <--- here, or on Section, or List
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            for _ in 0...24 { dataModel.items.append(IdentifiableString())}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @workingdog! I couldn't use the `@Observable` macro in my use case since my application is built to run on devices that are pre-iOS 17, but I was able to use your example to build an `@ObservableObject` workaround (which I'll post below).

Comment: updated my answer using `ObservableObject`. Although in this particular case, you could just use `@State private var items = [IdentifiableString]()` with `struct IdentifiableString` as declared in my example code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my adapted version of workingdog's answer:

```
class IdentifiableString: Identifiable, Hashable, ObservableObject {
    static func ==(lhs: IdentifiableString, rhs: IdentifiableString) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.id)
    }
    
    let id = UUID()
    @Published var string = ""
}

class IdentifiableStringArray: ObservableObject {
    @Published var array = [IdentifiableString]()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var resetUpdate = false
    
    @ObservedObject var identifibleStrings = IdentifiableStringArray()
    
    @State var id = false
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button("Set with Dummy Data") {
                resetUpdate = true
                                
                for (index, identifibleString) in identifibleStrings.array.enumerated() {
                    identifibleString.string = "\(index + 1)"
                }
                
                self.id.toggle()
            }
            .onChange(of: resetUpdate) { _, newValue in
                if newValue == true {
                    resetUpdate = false
                }
            }
            
            Button("Reset", role: .destructive) {
                for identifibleString in identifibleStrings.array {
                    identifibleString.string = ""
                }
                
                self.id.toggle()
            }
            
            Section {
                ForEach($identifibleStrings.array) { identifibleString in
                    
                    if let index = identifibleStrings.array.firstIndex(where: {$0 == identifibleString.wrappedValue}) {
                        TextField("Text Field \(index + 1)", text: identifibleString.string)
                    } else {
                        Text("Text Field could not be generated")
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Section {
                if !resetUpdate {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(identifibleStrings.array) { identifiableString in
                            if identifiableString.string != "" {
                                Text(identifiableString.string)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .id(id)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            for n in 1...15 {
                self.identifibleStrings.array.append(IdentifiableString())
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview("ContentView") {
    ContentView()
}
```